# Exporting openAPI specification with terraform + apigateway + AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I'd like to export my aws gateway api as a openapi documentation.

I see there is a module for that in the terraform aws documentation:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/apigatewayv2_export

However, I do not understand how this is actually used? The attribute references are ID and body, where the body is `ID of the API.`.

Should there not be a output path? How do you export the openapi documentation from terraform when using api gateway?

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation for that data source is wrong. I think `id` is almost certainly the "ID of the API" and `body` is probably the JSON or YAML output, which you would then use along with a [local_file](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file) resource if you want to write that to a file.

I suggest testing that, and at least create a temporary Terraform `output` from the `body` attribute to see what is actually in there. If the `body` is actually the JSON or YAML output, then I would ask that you please [file a ticket](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues) with HashiCorp to correct the documentation.